# Sign up buttons missing styles in anonymous voting dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, anonymous

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Log out
2. Click a vote button on a question
3. Observe the dialog that appears

### Actual Result

4. The dialog's "Sign up" buttons seems to be missing styles. They use the text cursor, not the pointer cursor, they don't visually respond to click or hover events, and they look ugly and as though they're missing padding.

   > [image]

### Expected Result

4. The dialog's "Sign up" buttons would appear and respond like buttons. Something like this:

   > [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We've just refactored the anonymous posting views and deleted some CSS that reached a little further than we'd hoped. This should now be fixed, and will go live in the next build.